# Unable to call plugin's method if I use virtual directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, nopcommerce, virtual-directory

I am implementing one plugin in nopCommerce. All thing works fine. But if I use virtual directory with my store I am not able to call plugin's method for CRUD operation. Moreover, I am using KendoGrid. In production the application is hosted under virtual directory www.mycompany.com/virtualdirectoryname

```
 transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/Admin/Plugins/MyPlugin/ListMethod",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            create: {
                url: "/Admin/Plugins/MyPlugin/InsertMethod",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            update: {
                url: "/Admin/Plugins/MyPlugin/UpdateMethod",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            destroy: {
                url: "/Admin/Plugins/MyPlugin/DeleteMethod",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        }
```

One more thing I use route provider to call plugin's method. It should redirect to www.mycompany.com/virtualdirectoryname/Admin/Plugins/MyPlugin/ListMethod but as per my routes it redirect to www.mycompany.com/Admin/Plugins/MyPlugin/ListMethod and because of this I am unable to perform any CRUD operation.

How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: which kind or error you get have your page is load or not..? if page load and grid is not load then check in console, grid fires ajax call check error and put it here so any one can evaluate it..

Comment: I have edited it. Can you please check it and suggest?